# Should I use ENT_QUOTES with htmlspecialchars or not

Tags: php, xss, sanitization

I am using php 5.4.4 running as UTF-8, and im not sure if I am using htmlspecialchars right.

My strings / vars look like this:

```
$text = "<p><span class='clx'>By:</span> ".htmlspecialchars($foo)."</span></p>";
echo $text;
```

Do I have need to use `ENT_QUOTES` or is that only necessary when I have to echo something

inside eg: `href="$foo" or id='$foo'` ?

Atm, om only using htmlspecialchars inside closed html tags and not attributes.

Just concatenate the var inside the string within a `<p>` tag and a `</p>` tag

Thanks

Comment: You should use it whenever you want to encode quotes in addition to the other html entities. To clarify, there are no set rules for when to use a function/argument. The only answer is, use it when you need it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should generally use it when taking data from database and inserting it into html elements. This is so that quotes from the data don't close the value quotes and mess up the html.

Comment: Thanks, im using it against XSS, am I using it right on my first code snippet? ...$text =

Comment: Since im not inserting data inside any attributes, just between open/closing tags

Comment: Yup, you're doing it right. ENT_QUOTES is not necessary in your first example.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: Always.

Long answer: I highly recommend reading OWASP's [PHP Top 5](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Top_5) and [PHP Security Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet)

The OWASP Top 5 covers the five most serious and common security vulnerabilities afflicting PHP today:

- Remote Code Execution
- Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) [The one htmlspecialchars is trying to prevent]
- SQL Injection
- PHP Configuration
- File System Attacks

It demonstrates common mistakes and solutions and is well worth reading for any PHP developer even considering hosting a live website.